# data type point[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm having trouble creating an index for `point[]` column.

```
create table test (pt point[]);
// Table created
create index pt_idx on test using gist (pt);
// Error creating index
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
data type point[] has no default operator class for access method "gist"
```

The same create index command work for `point` column but not for `point[]` column.
My postgresql version is 10.11.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: a gist index simply doesn't support arrays or points (see the supported data types and operators [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist-builtin-opclasses.html)). Can't you normalize the table, so that you don't need an array?

Comment: What kind of queries are you hoping to support?